# Dokku Multiple app in single repo

Tags: java, devops, paas, dokku

I have a maven project

```
pom.xml
service-a
service-b
```

I want to run service-a and service-b in dokku.

```
dokku apps:create service-a
dokku apps:create service-b

git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:service-a
# how to do this for service-b
```

How to tell dokku which service do I want to start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not officially supported, you can use the [dokku-monorepo plugin](https://github.com/iamale/dokku-monorepo) to handle this use case. Please refer to the documentation in that plugin for more information.